# Opening html content in new tab from bookmarklet (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

I had a few bookmarklets that used a technique like:

```
javascript:(function(){open('data:text/html,'+encodeURIComponent('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><h1>Title</h1>Content</body></html>'))})()
```

This basically opens some text/html content in a new tab/window using a data url.

This technique apparently does not work anymore in Firefox 61.0.1 (haven't tested other versions). Is this a bug or by design?

A particular implementation using a javascript url doesn't appear to work either.

If this is by design, then is there any simple alternative other than opening a new tab and then writing the content afterwards?

Note: I believe this restriction does not apply to plain text content (possibly others).

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

```
javascript:(function(){open('javascript:"'+encodeURIComponent('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><h1>Title</h1>Content</body></html>')+'"')})()
```

The above is a workaround. encodeURIComponent is useful if either double quotes or single quotes need to be escaped (but not both at the same time)